# Can I embed commands in one bash line?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix

I want to run the command:

```
$ cd which automator
```

so that the value returned by which automator is passed to cd. I've looked all over and cannot find a simple answer. Save me SO!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for:

```
cd "$(dirname "$(which automator)")"
```

- Generally, you need `$(...)` - a [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) - to use the output from a command as an argument to another command.
- In this case, because `which automator` returns a *file* path, you need *2* command substitutions: the first to get the executable file path with `which`, the 2nd to extract the *directory* path from it with `dirname`.
- Double-quoting the command substitutions is generally the right thing to do. If you don't, the command output is subject to word splitting and globbing (which are two instances of [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)), which is rarely what you want.

Comment: Much appreciated!